# React: How is event.target.value working in the following

Tags: reactjs

In the following code, I could not understand how event.target.value is working. I went through the documentation, but unfortunately I could not follow this. Can anyone please explain in simpler terms?

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './NewPost.css';

class NewPost extends Component {
    state = {
        title: '',
        content: '',
        author: 'Max'
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="NewPost">
                <h1>Add a Post</h1>
                <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text" value={this.state.title} onChange={(event) => this.setState({title: event.target.value})} />
                <label>Content</label>
                <textarea rows="4" value={this.state.content} onChange={(event) => this.setState({content: event.target.value})} />
                <label>Author</label>
                <select value={this.state.author} onChange={(event) => this.setState({author: event.target.value})}>
                    <option value="Max">Max</option>
                    <option value="Manu">Manu</option>
                </select>
                <button>Add Post</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default NewPost;
```

Answer (score 1):

The ["change" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) is a standard DOM event fired by `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements. The `onChange` handler and Event object in React are nearly identical to the native ones.

- `event.target` is the element where the event started
- [`HTMLInputElement.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes) is the current form of the form control

so...

- `event.target.value` is the current value of the `<input>` that triggered the "change" event

For most `onX` event handlers in React, the best documentation might be found in MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) for the associated native event.

Answer (score 0):

React uses [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) which is cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event.
React normalizes events so that they have consistent properties across different browsers.

Which is why when you [handle events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) in React, it is the same as native browser events.